# ZendFramework: Simple Router_Regex problem

Tags: regex, zend-framework

I have never been any good at regular expressions. I am trying to use them in building a simple site. I construct a URL just fine like `/some-course/some-vtm-1`, but when it tries to lookup the defined controller, it fails. Here is the route I have defined:

```
chapter' => array(
                'type'  => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex',
                'route' => '/:course/:vtm\-(\d+)',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'module'     => 'learn',
                    'controller' => 'chapter',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ),
                'map' => array(
                    1 => 'course',
                    2 => 'vtm',
                    3 => 'id'
                ),
                'reverse' => '%s/%s-%d/'
            ),
```

How should I correct this Regex so it finds the correct module/controller/action when I a link like `/some-course/some-vtm-1` is clicked

Comment: Why do you have backslash before minus/dash? I think you do not need to escape `-` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to mix the syntax of `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` (named variables in the route starting with `:`) and `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` (bracketed regular expression patterns in the route). You want to drop the former and just use the regexp syntax, leaving you with something like this:

```
array(
    'type'  => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex',
    'route' => '([\w]+)/(vtm)-([\d]+)',
     'defaults' => array(
        'module'     => 'learn',
        'controller' => 'chapter',
        'action'     => 'index'
     ),
     'map' => array(
         1 => 'course',
         2 => 'vtm',
         3 => 'id'
     ),
     'reverse' => '%s/%s-%d'
 ),
```

Comment: I tried your solution just now and it was still not matching on this route. I noticed you had (vtm) in there as a literal string. I tried your way, and `'route' => '([\w]+)/([\w]+)-([\d]+)'` which neither worked. I have hyphens in the first two path(s) before the trailing hyphen & integer, so I need to account for that as well.

Comment: Here is my working solution, I hope it's the "right" way to do it. `'route' => '([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)-([\d]+)',`